# window.getSelection() in Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

There is [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) in JS.
What is the equivalent in Kotlin/JS?
There is nothing in Kotlin [Window](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-window/) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it *is* present in the `kotlin-browser` module from the official [kotlin-wrappers](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/blob/master/kotlin-browser/README.md).

Instead of importing `kotlinx.browser.window`, use `web.window.window`:

```kotlin
import web.window.window

val selection = window.getSelection() ?: error("no selection")
```

Also, in general, if something is missing in Kotlin/JS types but you know the actual object has the method or property you need, you can always "force" your way by using `asDynamic()`:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.browser.window

val selection = window.asDynamic().getSelection() ?: error("no selection")
```

But this gives up type checking for the return value too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether this is the same or not. After searching found  [SelectionMode](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/924c28507067cbfbf78a6509ea89eabe496e34ca/libraries/stdlib/js/src/org.w3c/org.w3c.dom.kt#L6505) in Kotlin API reference https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-selection-mode.html

Also what will be the `window.getSelection()` be used for ?